# DS18B20 temperature sensor with Attiny25

Tags: sensor, avr, uart, temperature, 1-wire

I would like to make a simple thermal switch with attiny25 but first I need to read the temperature values from the ds18b20 sensor. I found some codes, here are the sources:
[DS18B20 lib](https://github.com/lpodkalicki/attiny-ds18b20-library)
[UART lib](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/code-c-avr-gcc-software-transmit-only-uart)

I need to use this uart implementation because the attiny25 does not have.
The UART function works well if I send characters but with the temperatures from the sensor it fails. I use the default 1MHz clock speed and 2400 baudrate.

I think the schematic is good, there is the 4,7kOhm pullup, and the data wire is connected. Vdd is 5V.

Could somebody help me please where to find the problem?
[All of "my" code is here](https://ufile.io/rf8kp)

Here is the onewire communication, is it good?
[image: onewire communication]

**EDIT1**:

Raised clock speed to 8Mhz, here is the 1Wire communication:
[image]
And the uart:
[image]

_delay_ms(1000) function is actually 0,9813s.
Is it possible, that the _delay_us() function is not very accurate so i got wrong timings?

**EDIT2**:

The reset condition was not enough, but that's not solved the problem.
Output of the onewire communication:
[image]

Comment: the  DS18B20 lib comes with an  example .... does the example work for you?

Comment: A very much doubt anyone on this website is dedicated enough to download that archive and try to debug it. Could you create a small self-contained example that shows the issue, and then post the code in the question? (Even if you get no answer, having a small bug reproducer helps a lot when debugging)

Comment: Going just by the described question, it's apparent there's an issue when soft 1-w and soft uart are interacting. I'm guessing, possibly one or both have interrupts that well ... interrupt the other, and introduce some delay in transfer, making it fail.

Comment: @jsotola no it does not work, the problem is that i get an error because of the low baud rate but i can't raise this, because of the 1MHz F_CPU clock speed.

Comment: @domen yes i will add more information to my question
Is it a good solution if i disable the interrupts before i send the data over the uart?

Comment: `error because of the low baud rate` ..... what error are you talking about? ..... why is this information missing from your question?

Comment: maybe you could use an LED as an output .... flash a code that represents the temperature ..... 20 degrees could be something like two short flashes followed by one long flash  .......... that would allow you to check if the sensor is supplying valid data without having to use serial comm

Comment: @jsotola I talk about an error what i got when i tried to compile the sample code from the ds18b20 lib (link) which is for attiny13. I know why i got it, the clock speed was low, so I replaced the uart.c with another implementation of uart (another link in the question). As i mentioned it works well alone. This error was missing from the question because i solved it.

(Later, i raised the clock speed to try out the original sample code, successfully complied, but uart "module" of it does not work. Possibly because it is for another series of avr.)

This is a good idea, i will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, if you are interested in:
https://github.com/toma3757/ATtiny25-DS18B20-UART

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using Arduino? I'm pretty sure the ATtiny board support package for ATtiny by David Mellis supports the ATTiny25. https://github.com/damellis/attiny

And then you could just use the tried and true Arduino library for the DS18B20 and OneWire. https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library

These libraries are pretty hardware agnostic as far as I know. With a try if you ask me. I think they bit-bang, possibly with some timer support.

Comment: Yes, i found it earlier but the attiny25's flash is too small for these libraries.
I compiled only the OneWIre and the DallasTemperature without the software serial lib, and it is 2452 byte. The flash size is 2kByte. 
However, thanks for the idea.